# I want to retrieve data from multiple tables to service payer into my project

Tags: c#, linq

want to retrieve data from multiple tables to service layer as I have to write database logic into service layer  into my project

> 'KeysPlus.Service.Models.QuoteModel' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Any help is highly appreciated!

```
public static IEnumerable<QuoteModel> GetJobQuotes(Login login, QuoteModel model)
{
    using (var db = new KeysEntities())
    {
        var quotes = db.JobQuote.Where( x=> x.ProviderId == login.Id);

        model = (from q in db.JobQuote
                 join j in db.Job on q.JobId equals j.Id
                 join p in db.Property on j.PropertyId equals p.Id
                 join a in db.Address on  p.AddressId equals a.AddressId
                 select new QuoteModel
                 {
                     JobDescription=j.JobDescription,
                     QuoteAmount=q.Amount,
                     PropertyAddress= a.City
                 }).ToList();
        return model;        
    }       
}
```

Comment: Do not change your question and invalidate the answers that have been given.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Sorry for that. I just updated because some other error is coming based on the changes which suggested by David

Comment: Then append the new code you have tried and the new error message. But you have said you want to return a list so using `.First()` makes no sense - that returns a single object.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Yes exactly, i want  to display the list from these tables. But if i put .ToList then this gives me error. Any suggestion is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have your read my answer. You need to remove the `QuoteModel model` parameter in your method and use `IEnumerable<QuoteModel> model = (from ...` or `var model = (from ...`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Thanks for your help. The return should be model or QuoteModel . If i give model then there is no error but again QuoteModel, its throwing error. Please advise.

Comment: What? Your assigning the collection to a variable named `model` so its `return model;` just as you code currently is (`QuoteModel` is the `type`)

Comment: But if you want to return a single `QuoteModel`, the the method must be `public static QuoteModel GetJobQuotes(Login login)` and then you use `.FirstOrDefault()` in the query.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Thank you a lot. your help solved my problems. I am getting the result now. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a parameter in your method named `model` which is a single `QuoteModel` and you trying to set its value to a collection of `QuoteModel`. Remove that parameter (you not using it) and change the code to

```
using (var db = new KeysEntities())
{
    var quotes = db.JobQuote.Where( x=> x.ProviderId == login.Id);
    IEnumerable<QuoteModel> model = (from q in db.JobQuote
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a model instance:

```
QuoteModel model
```

And you're trying to set it to a *collection* of model instances:

```
model = (from q in db.JobQuote
         ...
        ).ToList();
```

An apple is not a basket of apples.  So you need to do one of two things, depending on what you actually want this method to do...

**Return one model?**

If you're looking for a *specific* instance from that list, then you need to add a clause to the query to return just that instance.  Methods like `.First()` or `.FirstOrDefault()` can do that (or the `.Single()` equivalents).  For example, if you want an instance which matches a specific value, it might look something like this:

```
model = (from q in db.JobQuote
         ...
        ).First(j => j.ID == someIdentifier);
```

Where of course `someIdentifier` is some value you have which you can use in the query.  Perhaps `model.ID` or something like that?  Depends on how you want to query your data, which we don't know here.  But the point is that you need to return *one* model, not *many* models.

Additionally, you'd need to change the method's return type to `QuoteModel`, since you'd just be returning that one model instance.

**Return many models?**

Conversely, if you *do* want to return multiple models, then you can't put them in a variable which holds only one model.  Just return the value directly:

```
return (from q in db.JobQuote
        ...
       ).ToList();
```

(Of course, then you're not even *using* the `model` variable, so why require it?)

Comment: I want to display list from this tables and now i changed my code as per your suggestions. But still 'QuoteModel' is a type, which is not valid in the given context is coming.

Comment: @Rajesh: Clearly the changes you made have something invalid.  Can you update the question to show that code?

Comment: I have updated the questions, please give me some advise

Comment: @Rajesh: Are you referring to the `return QuoteModel;` line in the question revision history?  You can't return a *type*, you have to return an *object*.  That object has to be the same type as declared in the method's return type.